# Getting error "Void 0 is not function" on browser when using webpack to bundle typescript file

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, node-modules

I am using `webpack` with 4.8.1 version to bundle `typescript` which has 2.8.1 version but when i am using that bundled `js` on browser i am getting error `Void 0 is not function`.here is my webpack.config.js file

```
var glob = require("glob")module.exports={
entry:{
  LiveAgentApplication:"./Scripts/LiveAgent.Application.ts"
},output: {
    path:__dirname+'/dist',
    filename: '[name].bundle.js'
  },module: {
    rules: [
      { test: /\.ts$/, loader: 'ts-loader' }
    ]
  },optimization: {
    minimize: false
  }}
```

Here is my tsconfig.js

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "system",
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "removeComments": true,
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "outFile": "../../built/local/tsc.js",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node"
},
"include": [
    "./Scripts/*"
],
"exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
]}
```

And package.json is as follows:

```
{"name": "Resources",
 "version": "1.0.0",
 "description": "",
 "main": "index.js",
 "scripts": {
   "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
   "refreshVSToken ": "vsts-npm-auth -config .npmrc"
  },
 "keywords": [],
 "author": "",
 "license": "ISC",
 "dependencies": {
 "geofluent-bundle": "^1.0.3",
 "geofluent-chat-translation-bundle": "^1.0.2",
 "geofluent-common-bundle": "^1.0.3",
 "geofluent-itranslator-bundle": "^1.0.6",
 "geofluent-sdk-bundle": "^1.0.1",
 "geofluent-tokenizer-bundle": "^1.0.4",
 "install": "^0.11.0",
 "jquery": "^3.3.1",
 "npm": "^5.8.0",
 "ts-loader": "^4.2.0",
 "webpack": "^4.8.1",
 "webpack-cli": "^2.1.3",
 "webpack-system-register": "^1.6.0",
 },"devDependencies": {
 "@types/jquery": "^3.3.1"
}}
```

**Note:some of the node modules i am using are hosted on our organization's private NPM registry**

Comment: It's impossible to say what's wrong because an error occurs at runtime and isn't informative. Currently you're the only person who can debug it. Check the function where the error occurs in call stack. The question requires a way for other users to replicate the problem see, https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . This may not need private modules if the issue can be replicated without them.